# VPN trouble on wifi network change

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, vpn, l2tp

I have a weird problem with my VPN(l2tp/IPSec) recently.

At first when I added the VPN there was no problem but when i changed my WiFi connection (came home from work!) the blocked sites that i visited in my previous network weren't responding any more, everything else works fine for example I tried a blocked website that i have never visited and it works fine.

I tried cleaning my dns cache but no result + tried ping no result
tried deleting VPN connection and adding it after I joined the network.

Worked at first but not anymore (I am a software engineer i know its weird but it happened).

I tried other vpn protocols(open vpn, cisco) and all of them have this problem.

I use 20.04 version

Comment: You have told a story about your problem with no details, no Ubuntu version, no error messages, no logs. If, as you assert, you're a "software engineer", you should know how to describe a problem. Do so.

Comment: there is no more details, i have written the steps that i took and the whole scenario, if you are looking to google the error message or logs I know how to google too!, And i have mentioned the ubuntu version at the end of the post and the tags my condescending friend.

Comment: if you have a way to diagnose the problem I'm all ears

Comment: You haven't shown the commands, error messages, ... What do you expect to happen? What happens if you restart (down & up) the VPN?  You have changed its connectivity.

Comment: WHAT COMMANDS? It's a VPN connection and two wireless networks after the network is changed endpoints that were called at the last network cant be fetched in the new network! that is it no command no log no error message. I expect someone with the proper expertise to help me troubleshoot